# String concatenation using Bootstrap's Typeahead

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, bootstrap-typeahead

We are trying to print a list of names using a string that includes an array. We are working in an autocomplete input field inside a searchform and we are using Bootstrap's Typeahead script.

When we paste the results of an array "manually" it works but the problem is that when we use an `echo` to display all the values included then the result is taken as a single value.

```
<?php
$name = array(the_title('"','",'));

foreach ($name as &$name_value) {
   echo $name_value;                    // This prints:   "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3",
}
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='[<?php echo $name_value; ?>]'>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [PHP: json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
    $names = array('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3');
    echo '<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source=\''.json_encode($names).'\' />';
?>
```

Comment: Now we have almost the same problem because where we find the array `'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'` it should be the array of thousands of `the_title();` posts.

Every post title should be splitted up and taken as a unique value and not a unique string with the same value for all the post titles.

Comment: Show us more code. If you use [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function from WordPress, it returns ONE title. Therefore it has no sense to use it the way you do.